# Java: How to get the time on the hour?

Tags: java, time, hour

I need to know how to get the the time. I am trying to make it run something at the top of every hour( 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, etc.). If you could help me that would be great!

Comment: Google `java get time`

Comment: Have you done *any* research before asking this question?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run something hourly use [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

```
 long hour = 1000L*3600L;
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
      // Do this hourly
   }
 }, hour, hour); // first delay, period
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the Quartz library (a well known Java scheduler) with a cron expression like

```
0 0 * ? * *
```

( = When times matches 0 seconds, 0 minutes, any hour, every day);